# analytic function such that $|f(z) |= 1$ must be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

From an exercise in class:

> Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic such that $|f(z)|=1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

What's the shortest way to show that $f$ is constant without resorting to Cauchy-Riemann? I'm asking this as I resorted to the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: I think the maximum modulus principle gives you this fact most easily and directly

Answer (score 8):

Let's see here:

1. Little Picard Theorem.
2. Big Picard Theorem.
3. Liouville's Theorem
4. Open Mapping Theorem.
5. Maximum Modulus Principle.